# Using txt files in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a txt file which I need to access through python. The data in the txt file displays a football league in CSV format. The CSV data covers the games played, won and lost, where this will calculate the teams points (2 points for a win, 0 for a loss). I have an idea on how to start this but not sure if I have started on the right foot.

How do I calculate the total points for each team? And can I get the headings above the data from the txt file? (Team,Played, Won, Lost, Total) Any support would be appreciated.

CSV Data:

```
Liverpool,19,7,12
Chelsea,19,8,11
Arsenal,19,0,19
Tottenham,19,7,12
Man Utd,19,7,12
Man City,19,5,14
Southampton,19,3,16
```

Code:

```
    text_file = open ("leagueResults.txt","r")
    print (text_file.read())
    text_file.close()
```

Comment: look into the `csv` module.

Comment: Where is the question? Okay, you opened the file... Now what?

Comment: How do I calculate the total points for each team? And can I get the headings above the data from the txt file? (Team,Played, Won, Lost, Total)

Comment: That has nothing to do with using the text file, that's just processing the text after you've read it, which you showed you know how to do.

Comment: But if this data is updated, how can i produce some code to re-calculate the points?

Comment: If the data are on a .txt and the .txt gets updated then you will have to re-read the .txt

Comment: Better to use some simple SQL database than a CSV file if you'll be updating this frequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you should look into the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

However in your case since I assume you have just started learning python and the problem is relatively trivial we can do it by just reading the file line by line splitting on the delimiter `,`.

```
team_name = []
games_won = []

num_records = 0
with open('leagueResults.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        record = line.strip().split(',')
        team_name.append(record[0])
        games_won.append(record[2])
        num_records += 1

print("Points Table")
print("============")
for i in range(0, num_records):
    print("%s: %d" % (team_name[i], (int(games_won[i]) * 2)))
```

**Output:**

```
Points Table
============
Liverpool: 14
Chelsea: 16
Arsenal: 0
Tottenham: 14
Man Utd: 14
Man City: 10
Southampton: 6
```

Notice how I am only interested in the `team_name` and `games_won` since those are the only two actually required to calculate the amount of points per team in the problem (`games_played` is always `19` and `games_lost` has no affect on the total points as it is multiplied by a scale factor of `0` in the total points calculation).